# R - Copy negative sign from one to another column

Tags: r, if-statement, sign

I have a dataframe (df_ann) as shown here:

| Cha | Seg_value | Seg_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AXL2 | -0.654 | 2.965 |
| PTT1 | 1.957 | 1.84 |
| AXL2 | 2.654 | 0.989 |
| PTT1 | -1.038 | 0.85 |

I want to add the negative sign in the `Seg_value2` column if it is present in the `Seg_value` column.

Output should be:

| Cha | Seg_value | Seg_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AXL2 | -0.654 | -2.965 |
| PTT1 | 1.957 | 1.84 |
| AXL2 | 2.654 | 0.989 |
| PTT1 | -1.038 | -0.85 |

I have searched for the solution to the problem but did not find the answer. Anything would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can multiply by the `sign` of 'Seg_value'

```
df_ann$Seg_value2 <- with(df_ann, sign(Seg_value) * Seg_value2)
```

-output

```
df_ann
   Cha Seg_value Seg_value2
1 AXL2    -0.654     -2.965
2 PTT1     1.957      1.840
3 AXL2     2.654      0.989
4 PTT1    -1.038     -0.850
```

#### data

```
df_ann <- structure(list(Cha = c("AXL2", "PTT1", "AXL2", "PTT1"), Seg_value = c(-0.654, 
1.957, 2.654, -1.038), Seg_value2 = c(2.965, 1.84, 0.989, 0.85
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option (but not applicable if `0` is in `Seg_value`)

```
transform(
  df,
  Seg_value2 = Seg_value2 * Seg_value / abs(Seg_value)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. it is working but I am using the @akrun script due to simplicity. Anyway, Thank you once again for your kind help.